# Azure Data Factory expression evaluation failes

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory, lookup, foreach-loop-container

[image: Pipeline piece]

In the ForEach loop i have a "set variable" object where i want to catch the value from each Identifier.

The output from the Lookup looks like:

```json
{
    "count": 60,
    "value": [
        {
            "Identifier": "83667NED"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "83668NED"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "60006"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "37823wkk"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "60006eng"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "37823eng"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "84046ENG"
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "84046NED"
        }
]
```

My used expression:

```
@activity('LU_max_values').output.value[item().Identifier]
```

I need the value of the key Identifier in each loop to be set in my variable but i get the error:

```
The expression 'activity('LU_max_values').output.value[item().Identifier]' cannot be evaluated because property '84472ENG' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.
```

When i use the expression:

```
@activity('LU_max_values').output.value[item()].Identifier
```

the next error is raised

```
The expression 'activity('LU_max_values').output.value[item()].Identifier' cannot be evaluated because property '{ "Identifier": "84037NED" }' cannot be selected.
```

what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you need to check:

1. The Items section in your `For Each` should be more like this:

   ```
   @activity('LU_max_values').output.value
   ```
2. When accessing that item with the For Each loop should be more like this:

   ```
   @item().Identifier
   ```

Sample pipeline:

[image: Sample pipeline]

Comment: Thank you! step 2 (@item().Identifier) was indeed the one i was looking for. Strange that the wizard doesnot fullfill this statement correctly. Anyway... it workst fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the output of the Lookup as the Items to be looped on. See below :

[image]

Then, within your ForEach loop, you can get the value of the identifier with the expression `@item().Identifier` :

[image]

And there you get your variable set to the correct value.

[image]